# Using GROUP BY with FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2014, analytic-functions

I'm working with some data that is currently stored in 1 minute intervals that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #MinuteData
    (
      [Id] INT ,
      [MinuteBar] DATETIME ,
      [Open] NUMERIC(12, 6) ,
      [High] NUMERIC(12, 6) ,
      [Low] NUMERIC(12, 6) ,
      [Close] NUMERIC(12, 6)
    );

INSERT  INTO #MinuteData
        ( [Id], [MinuteBar], [Open], [High], [Low], [Close] )
VALUES  ( 1, '2015-01-01 17:00:00', 1.557870, 1.557880, 1.557870, 1.557880 ),
        ( 2, '2015-01-01 17:01:00', 1.557900, 1.557900, 1.557880, 1.557880 ),
        ( 3, '2015-01-01 17:02:00', 1.557960, 1.558070, 1.557960, 1.558040 ),
        ( 4, '2015-01-01 17:03:00', 1.558080, 1.558100, 1.558040, 1.558050 ),
        ( 5, '2015-01-01 17:04:00', 1.558050, 1.558100, 1.558020, 1.558030 ),
        ( 6, '2015-01-01 17:05:00', 1.558580, 1.558710, 1.557870, 1.557950 ),
        ( 7, '2015-01-01 17:06:00', 1.557910, 1.558120, 1.557910, 1.557990 ),
        ( 8, '2015-01-01 17:07:00', 1.557940, 1.558250, 1.557940, 1.558170 ),
        ( 9, '2015-01-01 17:08:00', 1.558140, 1.558200, 1.558080, 1.558120 ),
        ( 10, '2015-01-01 17:09:00', 1.558110, 1.558140, 1.557970, 1.557970 );

SELECT  *
FROM    #MinuteData;

DROP TABLE #MinuteData;
```

The values track currency exchange rates, so for each minute interval (bar), there is the `Open` price as the minute started and a `Close` price for the minute end. The `High` and `Low` values represent the highest and lowest rate during each individual minute.

**Desired Output**

I'm looking to reformat this data in to 5 minute intervals to produce the following output:

```
MinuteBar                Open       Close       Low         High
2015-01-01 17:00:00.000  1.557870   1.558030    1.557870    1.558100
2015-01-01 17:05:00.000  1.558580   1.557970    1.557870    1.558710
```

This takes the `Open` value from the first minute of the 5, the `Close` value from the last minute of the 5. The `High` and `Low` values represent the highest `high` and lowest `low` rates across the 5 minute period.

**Current Solution**

I have a solution that does this (below), but it feels inelegant as it relies on `id` values and self joins. Also, I intend to run it on much larger datasets so I was looking to do it in a more efficient manner if possible:

```
-- Create a column to allow grouping in 5 minute Intervals
SELECT  Id, MinuteBar, [Open], High, Low, [Close], 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-01-01T00:00:00', MinuteBar)/5 AS Interval
INTO    #5MinuteData
FROM    #MinuteData
ORDER BY minutebar

-- Group by inteval and aggregate prior to self join
SELECT  Interval ,
        MIN(MinuteBar) AS MinuteBar ,
        MIN(Id) AS OpenId ,
        MAX(Id) AS CloseId ,
        MIN(Low) AS Low ,
        MAX(High) AS High
INTO    #DataMinMax
FROM    #5MinuteData
GROUP BY Interval;

-- Self join to get the Open and Close values
SELECT  t1.Interval ,
        t1.MinuteBar ,
        tOpen.[Open] ,
        tClose.[Close] ,
        t1.Low ,
        t1.High
FROM    #DataMinMax t1
        INNER JOIN #5MinuteData tOpen ON tOpen.Id = OpenId
        INNER JOIN #5MinuteData tClose ON tClose.Id = CloseId;

DROP TABLE #DataMinMax
DROP TABLE #5MinuteData
```

**Rework Attempt**

Instead of the above queries, I've been looking at using [FIRST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) and [LAST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx), as it seems to be what I'm after, but I can't quite get it working with the grouping that I'm doing. There might be a better solution than what I'm trying to do, so I'm open to suggestions. Currently I'm trying to do this:

```
SELECT  MIN(MinuteBar) MinuteBar5 ,
        FIRST_VALUE([Open]) OVER (ORDER BY MinuteBar) AS Opening,
        MAX(High) AS High ,
        MIN(Low) AS Low ,
        LAST_VALUE([Close]) OVER (ORDER BY MinuteBar) AS Closing ,
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', MinuteBar) / 5 AS Interval
FROM    #MinuteData
GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', MinuteBar) / 5
```

This gives me the below error, which is related to the `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` as the query runs if I remove those lines:

> Column '#MinuteData.MinuteBar' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The first_value and last_value aren't actually aggregate functions like you might think. They're more like row_number, where they're windowed over a full data set. Problem is you're trying to use them like aggregates, and that's why it's yelling at you. I have to head out right now, but my first thought was to cast the date to a string, substring out the minute component and tape it back together in its rounded form.

Comment: thanks for the response, I haven't used first_value in anger before. the dates aren't really my problem here, I have a solution for that which seems to be working, although there could be better ways to do that. the main issue is getting the open and close values for the 5 minute periods.

Comment: so High and Low is simply the highest high and the lowest low respectively, but `open` and `close` are what you're having trouble with because those should just be the first and last in the interval, regardless of their value? Do I have that right?

Comment: @Xedni yeah that's correct. My current solution works, but I was hoping to do it in a better way. There may be a better way than what I'm trying and I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    MIN(MinuteBar) AS MinuteBar5,
    Opening,
    MAX(High) AS High,
    MIN(Low) AS Low,
    Closing,
    Interval
FROM 
(
    SELECT FIRST_VALUE([Open]) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', MinuteBar) / 5 ORDER BY MinuteBar) AS Opening,
           FIRST_VALUE([Close]) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', MinuteBar) / 5 ORDER BY MinuteBar DESC) AS Closing,
           DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', MinuteBar) / 5 AS Interval,
           *
    FROM #MinuteData
) AS T
GROUP BY Interval, Opening, Closing
```

A solution close to your current one. There are two places you did wrong.

1. FIRST_VALUE AND LAST_VALUE are *Analytic Functions*, which work on a window or partition, instead of a group. You can run the nested query alone and see its result.
2. LAST_VALUE is the last value of current window, which is not specified in your query, and a default window is rows from the first row of current partition to **current row**. You can either use FIRST_VALUE with descending order or specify a window

   ```
   LAST_VALUE([Close]) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', MinuteBar) / 5 
               ORDER BY MinuteBar 
               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS Closing,
   ```

Comment: Nice. I didn't think about adding Opening and Closing to the group by clause.

Comment: This seems like the tidiest solution that doesn't require as many steps as the others and is closest to what I was trying to achieve although I'm still looking at why the LAST_VALUE part doesn't work how I expected. Nonetheless, this works so thanks.

Comment: I would recommend replacing `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', MinuteBar) / 5` with `DATEPART(MINUTE, MinuteBar)/5`. Other then that, that's a solid solution. +1.

Comment: @ZoharPeled in fairness that's my code that he's copied. Although your solution will work for this dataset, it wouldn't work across larger datasets. When I use this in reality I will be running it across maybe 10 years worth of data. BTW Thanks for answering.

Comment: +1 For the following (important) clarification "(...) a default window is rows from the first row of current partition to current row"

Comment: nice explanation on why last_value doesn't work as expected with default window

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it without temporary tables:

```
;WITH CTEInterval AS 
(  -- This replaces your first temporary table (#5MinuteData)
    SELECT  [Id], 
            [MinuteBar], 
            [Open], 
            [High], 
            [Low], 
            [Close],
            DATEPART(MINUTE, MinuteBar)/5 AS Interval
    FROM #MinuteData
), CTEOpenClose as 
( -- this is instead of your second temporary table (#DataMinMax)
    SELECT  [Id], 
            [MinuteBar], 
            FIRST_VALUE([Open]) OVER (PARTITION BY Interval ORDER BY MinuteBar) As [Open],
            [High],
            [Low], 
            FIRST_VALUE([Close]) OVER (PARTITION BY Interval ORDER BY MinuteBar DESC) As [Close],
            Interval
    FROM CTEInterval
)

-- This is the final select
SELECT  MIN([MinuteBar]) as [MinuteBar], 
        AVG([Open]) as [Open], -- All values of [Open] in the same interval are the same...
        AVG([Close]) as [Close],  -- All values of [Close] in the same interval are the same...
        MIN([Low]) as [Low], 
        MAX([High]) as [High]
FROM CTEOpenClose
GROUP BY Interval
```

Results:

```
MinuteBar                Open       Close       Low         High
2015-01-01 17:00:00.000  1.557870   1.558030    1.557870    1.558100
2015-01-01 17:05:00.000  1.558580   1.557970    1.557870    1.558710
```

Comment: Thanks I'll test this shortly, currently in a meeting. I was hoping to go reduce the number of steps and I want something that will perform well over approximately 600,000+ records. Will respond later once I've tested

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[Demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/619690)</kbd>

```
;with cte
as
(--this can be your permanent table with intervals ,rather than generating on fly
select cast('2015-01-01 17:00:00.000' as datetime) as interval,dateadd(mi,5,'2015-01-01 17:00:00.000') as nxtinterval
union all
select dateadd(mi,5,interval),dateadd(mi,5,nxtinterval) from cte
where interval<='2015-01-01 17:45:00.000'

)
,finalcte
as
(select minutebar,
low,high,
dense_rank() over (order by  interval,nxtinterval) as grpd,
last_value([close]) over ( partition by interval,nxtinterval order by interval,nxtinterval) as [close],
first_value([open]) over (partition by interval,nxtinterval order by interval,nxtinterval) as [open]
 from cte c
join
#minutedata m
on m.minutebar between interval and nxtinterval
)
select 
min(minutebar) as minutebar,
min(low) as 'low',
max(high) as 'High',
max([open]) as 'open',
max([close]) as 'close'
 from finalcte
 group by grpd
```

Comment: how did you get the "Demo here" button?

Comment: @Xedni: use <kbd> keep some text </kbd>