# How can I UPDATE a table based on another table, using values from groups of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
   Site       ????         ????,
   WorkTypeId char(2)  NOT NULL,
   Emp_NO     int      NOT NULL,
   "Date"     ????     NOT NULL  
);

CREATE TABLE PTO (
   Site       ????         ????,
   WorkTypeId char(2)      NULL,
   Emp_NO     int      NOT NULL,
   "Date"     ????     NOT NULL  
);
```

I would like to update values in `PTO`'s `WorkTypeId` column:

1. `EMP NO` in `Employee` (the lookup table) and `PTO` should match.
2. A single `WorkTypeId` value should be picked from only the first occurrence of the month.

For example, given this sample input data:

**`TABLE Employee`**:

| Site | WorkTypeId | Emp_NO | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5015 | MB | 1005 | 2022-02-01 |
| 5015 | MI | 1005 | 2022-02-04 |
| 5015 | PO | 1005 | 2022-02-04 |
| 5015 | ME | 2003 | 2022-01-01 |
| 5015 | TT | 2003 | 2022-01-10 |

**`TABLE PTO`**:

| Site | WorkTypeId | Emp_NO | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5015 |  | 1005 | 2022-02-03 |
| 5015 |  | 1005 | 2022-02-14 |
| 5014 |  | 2003 | 2022-01-09 |

For example:

- Given `Employee` with `Emp_NO = 1005`...

  - ...there are 3 rows for that `Emp_NO` in the `Employee` table, with 3 distinct `WorkTypeId` values, but differing `Date` values.
  - So pick the `WorkTypeId` value for the earliest `Date` (2022-02-01), which is `'MB'`
  - So `Emp_NO` gets `WorkTypeId = 'MB'`.
  - And use that single value to fill `1005`'s `WorkTypeId` cells in the `PTO` table.
  - **But also match by month**.

So the expected output in the `PTO` table is

| Site | WorkTypeId | Emp_NO | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5015 | MB | 1005 | 2022-02-03 |
| 5015 | MB | 1005 | 2022-02-14 |
| 5014 | ME | 2003 | 2022-01-09 |

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us table and view definitions, sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh I have updated the data into text ,Also DBMS I am suing is SQL server

Comment: `Single Work type should be picked from only the first occurrence of the month` What about "Site"? The PTO table contains Site# as well.  Do you want the the 1st occurrence of the month per "Emp_No" **and** "Site" or just Emp_No only?

Comment: Only Emp_no's 1 st occurrence

Comment: When you say "Update values", do you mean you want to run an `UPDATE` DML statement to modify data on-disk, or do you mean you just want to transform/mutate the query's return values inside a (inherently read-only) `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @RohanJaiswal I've reworded and reformatted your question for clarity. Please improve upon my changes if I've misunderstood you. Also, please complete the `CREATE TABLE` statements by replacing the `????` placeholders with the _actual_ column types. **It's important that we know exactly what column-type the `Date` columns have**.

Comment: If `Employee` really is the name of the table, then it needs a better name because it doesn't actually contain Employee records (i.e. where `Emp_No` is the `PRIMARY KEY`).

Comment: @RohanJaiswal In your post you said that values should also match by month, but that adds ambiguity. Please update your example data to show how data for the same `Emp_No` for multiple months should work.

Comment: @RohanJaiswal What should happen if an `Emp_No` row in `PTO.WorkTypeId` _already has_ a non-`NULL` value? Should it overwrite it, preserve it, or be added as a new separate row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a value from a column *different* to the column used in a `MIN`/`MAX` expression in a `GROUP BY` query still remains a surprisingly difficult thing to do in SQL, and while modern versions of the SQL language (and SQL Server) make it easier, they're completely non-obvious and counter-intuitive to most people as it necessarily involves more advanced topics like CTEs, derived-tables (aka inner-queries), self-joins and windowing-functions *despite* the conceptually simple nature of the query.

Anyway, as-ever in modern SQL, there's usually 3 or 4 different ways to accomplish the same task, with a few gotchas.

#### Preface:

- As `Site`, `Date`, `Year`, and `Month` are all keywords in T-SQL, I've escaped them with double-quotes, which is the ISO/ANSI SQL Standards compliant way to escape reserved words.

  - SQL Server supports this by default. If (for some ungodly reason) you have `SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER OFF` then change the double-quotes to square-brackets: `[]`
- I assume that the `Site` column in both tables is just a plain' ol' data column, as such:

  - It is not a `PRIMARY KEY` member column.
  - It should not be used as a `GROUP BY`.
  - It should not be used in a `JOIN` predicate.
- All of the approaches below assume this database state:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Employee" (
    "Site"     int      NOT NULL,
    WorkTypeId char(2)  NOT NULL,
    Emp_NO     int      NOT NULL,
    "Date"     date     NOT NULL  
);

CREATE TABLE "PTO" (
    "Site"     int      NOT NULL,
    WorkTypeId char(2)      NULL,
    Emp_NO     int      NOT NULL,
    "Date"     date     NOT NULL  
);

GO

INSERT INTO "Employee" ( "Site", WorkTypeId, Emp_NO, "Date" )
VALUES
( 5015, 'MB', 1005, '2022-02-01' ),
( 5015, 'MI', 1005, '2022-02-04' ),
( 5015, 'PO', 1005, '2022-02-04' ),
( 5015, 'ME', 2003, '2022-01-01' ),
( 5015, 'TT', 2003, '2022-01-10' );

INSERT INTO "PTO" ( "Site", WorkTypeId, Emp_NO, "Date" )
VALUES
( 5015, NULL, 1005, '2022-02-03' ),
( 5015, NULL, 1005, '2022-02-14' ),
( 5014, NULL, 2003, '2022-01-09' );
```

- Both approaches define CTEs `e` and `p` that extend `Employee` and `PTO` respectively to add computed `"Year"` and `"Month"` columns, which avoids having to repeatedly use `YEAR( "Date" ) AS "Year"` in `GROUP BY` and `JOIN` expressions.

  - I suggest you add those as computed-columns in your base tables, if you're able, as they'll be useful generally anyway. Don't forget to index them appropriately too.

#### Approach 1: Composed CTEs with elementary aggregates, then `UPDATE`:

```sql
WITH
-- Step 1: Extend both the `Employee` and `PTO` tables with YEAR and MONTH columns (this simplifies things later on):
e AS (
    SELECT
        Emp_No,
        "Site",
        WorkTypeId,
        "Date",

        YEAR( "Date" ) AS "Year",
        MONTH( "Date" ) AS "Month"
    FROM
        Employee
),
p AS (
    SELECT
        Emp_No,
        "Site",
        WorkTypeId,
        "Date",

        YEAR( "Date" ) AS "Year",
        MONTH( "Date" ) AS "Month"
    FROM
        PTO
),
-- Step 2: Get the MIN( "Date" ) value for each group:
minDatesForEachEmployeeMonthYearGroup AS (
    SELECT
        e.Emp_No,
        e."Year",
        e."Month",

        MIN( "Date" ) AS "FirstDate"
    FROM
        e
    GROUP BY
        e.Emp_No,
        e."Year",
        e."Month"
),
-- Step 3: INNER JOIN back on `e` to get the first WorkTypeId in each group:
firstWorkTypeIdForEachEmployeeMonthYearGroup AS (
    /* WARNING: This query will fail if multiple rows (for the same Emp_NO, Year and Month) have the same "Date" value. This can be papered-over with GROUP BY and MIN, but I don't think that's a good idea at all). */
    SELECT
        e.Emp_No,
        e."Year",
        e."Month",

        e.WorkTypeId AS FirstWorkTypeId
    FROM
        e
        INNER JOIN minDatesForEachEmployeeMonthYearGroup AS q ON
            e.Emp_NO = q.Emp_NO
            AND
            e."Date" = q.FirstDate
)
-- Step 4: Do the UPDATE.
-- *Yes*, you can UPDATE a CTE (provided the CTE is "simple" and has a 1:1 mapping back to source rows on-disk).
UPDATE
    p
SET
    p.WorkTypeId = f.FirstWorkTypeId
FROM
    p
    INNER JOIN firstWorkTypeIdForEachEmployeeMonthYearGroup AS f ON
        p.Emp_No = f.Emp_No
        AND
        p."Year" = f."Year"
        AND
        p."Month" = f."Month"
WHERE
    p.WorkTypeId IS NULL;
```

Here's a screenshot of SSMS showing the contents of the `PTO` table from before, and after, the above query runs:

[image]

#### Approach 2: Skip the self-`JOIN` with `FIRST_VALUE`:

This approach gives a shorter, slightly simpler query, but requires SQL Server 2012 or later (and that your database is running in compatibility-level 110 or higher).

Surprisingly, [you cannot use `FIRST_VALUE` in a `GROUP BY` query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840829/using-group-by-with-first-value-and-last-value), despite its obvious similarities with `MIN`, but an equivalent query can be built with `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```sql
WITH
-- Step 1: Extend the `Employee` table with YEAR and MONTH columns:
e AS (
    SELECT
        Emp_No,
        "Site",
        WorkTypeId,
        "Date",

        YEAR( "Date" ) AS "Year",
        MONTH( "Date" ) AS "Month"
    FROM
        Employee
),
firstWorkTypeIdForEachEmployeeMonthYearGroup AS (

    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        e.Emp_No,
        e."Year",
        e."Month",
        FIRST_VALUE( WorkTypeId ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                Emp_No,
                e."Year",
                e."Month"
            ORDER BY
                "Date" ASC
        ) AS FirstWorkTypeId
    FROM
        e
)
-- Step 3: UPDATE PTO:
UPDATE
    p
SET
    p.WorkTypeId = f.FirstWorkTypeId
FROM
    PTO AS p
    INNER JOIN firstWorkTypeIdForEachEmployeeMonthYearGroup AS f ON
        p.Emp_No = f.Emp_No
        AND
        YEAR( p."Date" ) = f."Year"
        AND
        MONTH( p."Date" ) = f."Month"
WHERE
    p.WorkTypeId IS NULL;
```

Doing a `SELECT * FROM PTO` after this runs gives me the exact same output as Approach 2.

##### Approach 2b, but made shorter:

Just so @SOS doesn't feel *too smug* about their SQL being considerably more shorter than mine , the *Approach 2* SQL above can be compacted down to this:

```sql
WITH empYrMoGroups AS (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT
        e.Emp_No,
        YEAR( e."Date" ) AS "Year",
        MONTH( e."Date" ) AS "Month",
        FIRST_VALUE( e.WorkTypeId ) OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                e.Emp_No,
                YEAR( e."Date" ),
                MONTH( e."Date" )
            ORDER BY
                e."Date" ASC
        ) AS FirstWorkTypeId
    FROM
        Employee AS e
)
UPDATE
    p
SET
    p.WorkTypeId = f.FirstWorkTypeId
FROM
    PTO AS p
    INNER JOIN empYrMoGroups AS f ON
        p.Emp_No = f.Emp_No
        AND
        YEAR( p."Date" ) = f."Year"
        AND
        MONTH( p."Date" ) = f."Month"
WHERE
    p.WorkTypeId IS NULL;
```

- The execution-plans for both *Approach 2* and *Approach 2b* are almost identical, excepting that *Approach 2b* has an extra Computed Scalar step for some reason.
- The execution plans for *Approach 1* and *Approach 2* are very different, however, with *Approach 1* having more branches than *Approach 2* despite their similar semantics.
- But my execution-plans won't match yours because it's very context-dependent, especially w.r.t. what indexes and PKs you have, and if there's any other columns involved, etc.

*Approach 1*'s plan looks like this:

[image]

*Approach 2b*'s plan looks like this:

[image]

@SOS's plan, for comparison, is a lot simpler... and I honestly don't know why, but it does show how good SQL Server's query optimizer is thesedays:

[image]

Comment: Very interesting (and thorough)! What version of SQL Server was used for the tests? I tested with SQL Server 2016 and about ~35k rows of random data. What surprised me (though maybe it shouldn't) was that despite the simpler plan for APPLY, when I tested all 4 queries the IO statistics were consistently *better for "Approach 1" than APPLY* (or the other approaches).  Approach 1 had consistently lower numbers (CPU/elapsed time/scan count/logical reads).  [Approach 1 Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1waXqZZc) and [APPLY plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJe145Wb9)

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2002-03-05**

Leaving this here for posterity, but I'd recommend reading [Dai's excellent write up on different approaches to this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71360743/8895292).

---

Try a CROSS APPLY to grab the first Employee record with a matching month and year.

*Note: Use OUTER APPLY to always return all PTO records, even when no matching WorkTypeId was found.*

```
SELECT p.Site
       , e.WorkTypeId
       , p.Emp_No
       , p.[Date]
FROM  PTO p CROSS APPLY 
        (
          SELECT TOP 1 WorkTypeId
          FROM   Employee e 
          WHERE  e.Emp_No = p.Emp_No
          AND    MONTH(e.[Date]) = MONTH(p.[Date])
          AND    YEAR(e.[Date]) = YEAR(p.[Date])
          ORDER BY [Date] ASC
        )e
```

**Results:**

```
Site | WorkTypeId | Emp_No | Date      
---: | :--------- | -----: | :---------
5015 | MB         |   1005 | 2022-02-03
5015 | MB         |   1005 | 2022-02-14
5014 | ME         |   2003 | 2022-01-09
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=41ba22d001b7b1a41c103b12eb137204)*

Comment: How is an `OUTER APPLY` better to any other `JOIN` type in this situation? As this is evaluated per-row, I think the execution-plan would be excessively expensive... can you show us the plan you get?

Comment: @Dai - Yeah, I agree the plan is not ideal.  The reason for using APPLY was that it seemed like they only needed the first matching row for an employee for the same month/year. Since there's no start/end date range in either table, I couldn't think of a reasonable JOIN to use.  Only subqueries or APPLY.  If you can think of a better option, I'm all ears. Always up for learning something new  :-)

Comment: I just posted my solution now, if you're interested: instead of `APPLY`, it uses a `GROUP BY year+month` query with a self-JOIN to get the first values for each employee's month range - as well as a simpler query that uses `FIRST_VALUE`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71360743/159145

Comment: Out of curiosity, I ran your version (though I changed it to an `UPDATE p FROM PTO CROSS APPLY( .. )` statement) and to my surprise the execution-plan for that was a _lot_ simpler than any of my queries - which surprised me because I thought that an `APPLY`-type `JOIN` to a `SELECT TOP` derived-table would always result in a RBAR-query, instead it actually was a _single_ table-scan (and sort) - so I'm happy to learn something new today _upvoted!_