# Linq Select new with GroupBy and OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

For the given data set, I want to return the unique rows for each `OrderId` that has the lowest number for `Status`, so the result would be:

[image]

I have a working query that does that:

```
var result = _dbContext.Orders
        .GroupBy(s => s.OrderId)
        .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x => x.Status).First()).ToList();
```

However, I would like to modify this query to only return three selected fields for each table row, rather than the dozens that exist. I know I need to add something like this:

```
.Select(group => new
{
    OrderId = ???,
    Status = ???,
    Date = ???
}
```

But I am unable to add this to my existing query and have it still work. How can I do this?

Comment: In SQL you'd use MIN(Status). It's the same here. As for `Date` - which date would you expect? Earliest? Latest?

Comment: Whichever `Date` exists for the record with the lowest `Status`

Comment: First, there's no `Date` in your data. Second, there's no "whichever" in SQL. *You* have to specify that with an aggregate function. The answer you accepted doesn't do what you asked. It doesn't group items with `GROUP BY`. It executes a `SELECT TOP 1 OrderID, Status, Date ORDER BY Status` for every Order ID. That's far, far more expensive than a simple query. What you seem to be asking is how to return the data of the  *row* with the lowest status.

Comment: What you try to do right now is very, very slow. There are ways to speed this up in T-SQL and possibly LINQ. There are several similar SO questions already. You'll have to post the actual table schema and actual sample data though. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840829/using-group-by-with-first-value-and-last-value) asks how to return the first and last stock price per date for example. This can be done with `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, you are correct. I would like to return the row with the lowest `Status` for each `OrderId`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try to do something like this:**

```
var result = _dbContext.Orders
    .GroupBy(s => s.OrderId)
    .Select(group => group.OrderBy(x => x.Status).First())
    .Select(order => new 
    {
        OrderId = order.OrderId,
        Status = order.Status,
        Date = order.Date
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you'd use:

```
SELECT OrderID,MIN(Status) as Status
FROM Orders
GROUP BY OrderID
```

A LINQ query is similar:

```
var query = context.Orders
                   .GroupBy(o=>o.OrderId)
                   .Select(g=> new {
                       OrderId=g.Key.OrderId,
                       Status=g.Min(o=>o.Status)
                   });
var results=query.ToList();
```

Comment: Is Min convertible to a Linq query?  A lot of those functions aren't.

Comment: From the very first day. These are basic aggregate functions, not BCL-specific calls

Comment: This seems to be the better solution as the currently accepted answer would very likely issue a less efficient query.